# Can't close a bootstrap modal after mailto link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, mailto

I have a bootstrap modal where the users fill out a form and upon clicking submit, it opens the user's mail client using a mailto link and populates a new message.

I would like the modal to close when this happens, but when I add code to close the modal, the mailto link no longer works (mail client window does not open). The modal successfully closes. Any suggestions?

```js
 $('#request-form').submit(function (evt) {               
            if ($("#request-form").valid())
            {
                evt.preventDefault();

                var firstName = $("#FirstName").val();
                var lastName = $("#LastName").val();
                var company = $("#Firm").val();
                var address = $("#Address").val();
                var city = $("#City").val();
                var state = $("#State").val();
                var zip = $("#Zip").val();
                var phone = $("#Phone").val();
                var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();
                var product = $("#ProductName").val();

                //Send email using mailto link
                var body = "Send this email <removed>.%0D%0A%0D%0AFirst Name: " + firstName + "%0D%0ALast Name: " + lastName + "%0D%0ACompany: " + company +
                    "%0D%0AAddress: " + address + "%0D%0ACity: " + city + "%0D%0AState: " + state + "%0D%0AZip: " + zip + "%0D%0APhone: " + phone + "%0D%0AEmail: " + email +
                    "%0D%0AProduct: " + product;

                var subject = "Product Request";
                var recipient = $("#Recipient").val();

                window.location.href = "mailto:" + recipient + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;                    
                $("#questions-modal").modal('hide');


            }               
        });
```

cshtml:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-nav pull-right" id="btn-openMail" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
```

Comment: [Works in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oywcgs00/)

Comment: This code fragment seems incomplete. Please include your full JS.

Comment: Updated my snippet to include the whole function. The fiddle worked, interesting... can't see how to relate what you did there to make changes on my end, though.

Comment: OMG it was the wrong modal id in the selector. That was it! It's supposed to be "#request-modal" not "#questions-modal"!! Whoops. It works now with using modal('hide'). I did not need the data-dismiss="modal" by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with "toggle"...

```
$("#questions-modal").modal('toggle');
```

or put some extra code.

Did you check console logs?